# How do I get my terminal to work in VS Code? Exit Code:2, doesn't allow me to type anything

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal, crash, freeze

This is my first – ever post on Stack Overflow and it’s about an issue with the functionality of the VS Code terminal. Whenever I would run a piece of code via the terminal, the terminal would operate for several seconds and disappear. I would then be presented with a dialog box on the bottom – right corner of the screen, informing me that the terminal terminated with an exit code of ‘2’. Sometimes, the exit code would be different. It would be ‘3’, ‘1’, ‘-3’, or ‘-1’ depending on the situation. I’ve tried uninstalling VS Code, Windows Terminal, Windows Powershell and re – installing those programs only for the same issue to reoccur.

I also have an issue with the terminal not accepting input i.e., when you would type a line of syntax in the terminal, it freezes, causing the input to be unrecognizable. The operation stalled. There were plenty of articles that I read on Stack Overflow in relation to my issues, but none were successful. I’m reaching out for assistance from anyone and am open to any suggestions in regards to this matter.

Genuinely,
Jayloneal